# How to assign a value to a variable based off array data

Tags: c++

I'm new to this board, and to be honest, I have been beating my head against the wall attempting to complete this last portion of this project. I got everything else working wonderfully. Long story short, I need to apply the associated string values to the variable **day**. Which string is based off of the data in the array "hotdogs[] and the corresponding value "largest".

"Largest" is the biggest number in the "hotdogs[]" array. My thinking of this is if array element 0 in hotdogs[] is not the largest, move onto the else if, and so on until it finds which element of array hotdogs[] is the largest variable.

The whole thing compiles and runs, but keeps giving me the same answer. That day "7" has the most sold hot dogs. Regardless of where the largest number is entered. Since I need a 10 ranking to post pics, I'll copy past the code.

```
 for (h=0; h<=6; h++)
{
    cin >> hotdogs[h];
    hdogsales = hdogsales + hotdogs[h];
}
for (int h=0; h<=6; h++)
{
    if(hotdogs[h] > largest)
    largest=hotdogs[h];
}

 {
    if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
    day = "1";
    else if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
    day = "2";
    else if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
    day = "3";
    else if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
    day = "4";
    else if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
    day = "5";
    else if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
    day = "6";
    else if (hotdogs[h] == largest);
    day = "7";
}
```

I would REALLY appreciate help on this. It is driving me nuts already. I have an inkling that the parameters I'm setting in my if statement is the culprit, but for the life of me, I cannot think what else to use in there.

Comment: Set `largest= hotdogs[0];` *prior* to entering the loop (and optionally start the loop at 1). As-wrtten, `largest` is in determine entering the loop, and thus evaluating it is undefined behavior. And `h` is accesing `hotdogs[]` our of bounds anyway once you finish the for-loop.

Comment: @user: A tip. Most experts can read code faster than they can read English. As much as possible, use your code to explain your problem. Of course, you should leave out parts that are not relevant. For example, show your code and then put in a comment like "var seems to be assigned 2 rather than 3 as I expect."

Comment: There's a `std::max_element` function that finds the max element, and the index can be extracted from the result with `std::distance`.

Comment: in my declarations, I have largest = hotdogs[0]. I didn't copy this over because I didn't think that was the problem area.

Comment: That sequence of `if`/`else if` conditions looks suspicious. The conditions are all the same.

Comment: You're comparing the same value, `hotdogs[h]` against `largest` in *every* one of your conditions. Are you expecting that to somehow change between each invoke (which, frankly, it *could* since `h` is now 7 and you're indexing beyond your array boundaries and into UB).

Comment: @RetoKoradi, you're correct which is why I believe I'm getting the same output every time. I think a function would be the way to go as chris states, but my professor wants us to use just arrays, loops, etc, as we are just learning functions now.

Comment: @WhozCraig, what would you recommend? I felt that was the problem, but I tried every variation I could think of. I was doing if (hotdogs[0] == largest); day = "1"; etc.

Comment: To directly fix the problem, I think you just want to change the series of if statements to compare to `hotdogs[0]`, `hotdogs[1]`, etc, instead of `hotdogs[h]`. And as one of the responders below spotted, remove the stray semicolon.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, I changed it to that just now. Same result as before. Still having output saying day = "7"

Comment: And you removed the extra semicolon as well?

Comment: @RetoKoradi you're the GREATEST! I didn't know what you were talking about haha. Was wondering what darned ; you were talking about. I need it at the end of 7... but then saw the last if statement ended with a ;. Thanks so much! Works perfect now!

Comment: @Leigh was the one who mentioned the extra semicolon first. I hadn't originally noticed it. Glad it works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `day` always being `7`, this is probably your problem.

```
else if (hotdogs[h] == largest);
day = "7";
```

With this, it's equivalent to this:

```
else if (hotdogs[h] == largest) {
    ;
}
day = "7";
```

That's the problem with not using braces; if there's an extra `;` it eats up the `if/else` condition and then the next line is *always* executed.

You should probably refactor that whole loop down to be set at the same time as the top loop, as well:

```
for (int h=0; h<=6; h++)
{
    if(hotdogs[h] > largest)
    {
        largest=hotdogs[h];
        day = h;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. how could this be rectified though? Make separate if statements, opening and closing braces for each set of conditions?

Comment: See the amendment; it's probably easier to set `day` when you're finding out which is the largest. My example sets the number but you could change that line to whatever format you so desire. For the `;` error, just remove that `;` and it would theoretically always end up with `day` being `"1"` because all conditions are the same. If you don't have braces around the `if` lines it executes up to the first `;`.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. Leigh gave me the correct answer looked right over, and disregarded. Deleted it, and it works perfectly now. Lesson learned: check, check twice, and check thrice for proper punctuation.

Comment: @user3600284 Fantastic. You may want to consider [reading the FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) of how this site works, and up-tick any answers you find helpful. if an answer provides the "best" solution for your needs, you should "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just should add a loop in line 11, just like this:

```
for (h = 0; h <= 6; h++)
{
    cin >> hotdogs[h];
    hdogsales = hdogsales + hotdogs[h];
}
for (int h = 0; h <= 6; h++)
{
    if (hotdogs[h] > largest)
        largest = hotdogs[h];
}
for (int h = 0; h <= 6; h++)
{
    if (hotdogs[h] == largest)
        day = to_string(h + 1);
}
cout << day;
```

EDIT : sorry i missunderstanded the question, here it is i think :)

Comment: This code makes about as little sense as the original one. It still has an if statement with the same condition 7 times.

Comment: was gonna say the same thing.

Comment: @user3600284 i'm sorry missunderstanded the question, now i think it's fine

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. Leigh gave me the correct answer looked right over, and disregarded. Deleted it, and it works perfectly now. Lesson learned: check, check twice, and check thrice for proper punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hotdogs[7] = { 12, 43, 76, 23, 98, 1, 27 };
    int hdogsales = accumulate(begin(hotdogs), end(hotdogs), 0);


    auto bestDay = std::distance(begin(hotdogs), 
                    std::max_element(begin(hotdogs), end(hotdogs)));

    cout << "total sales for the week: " << hdogsales << endl;
    cout << "best day was day " << to_string(bestDay + 1) << " with " << hotdogs[bestDay] << " sales\n";

    return 0;
}
```